# passing command from awk to the next command using xargs

Tags: shell, amazon-ec2, awk, aws-cli, xargs

I am using AWS EC2 CLI to perform a filter on stopped instances, then create an AMI out of these with the AMI name taken from the instance tag.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --profile proj --query 'Reservations[*].[Instances[*].[InstanceId, InstanceType, State.Name, Platform, Placement.AvailabilityZone, PublicIpAddress, PrivateIpAddress,[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value][0][0]]]'  --filter --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped | awk '{print $1, $8}' | xargs -n2 aws ec2 create-image --profile proj --instance-id {} --name {} --no-reboot
```

how to let args differentiate the two different parameters from AWK (instnaceid, instance name tag), thereby it can be correctly pumped into the ec2 create-image on the instance-id and --name parameter accordingly

Comment: Could you please do add more details(like what is the role of awk in your requirement etc)  in your question as its not clear.

Comment: the role of awk is to filter the results in columns, in which the first column is instance-id, and the second column is the ec2 instance name.

Comment: I believe your question could be simplified. Let's say you have a script "X" (awk in this instance), your question is how to have xargs parse the output of "X". Would you consider to remove awk from the question? You could equate the output of awk to an input text file.

Comment: I believe even after remove the awk from the question, the context would still be the same. The context is still on how to pass the parameter from the input to the next command ec2-create-image using xargs

Comment: @user2155404 use of `awk` here is totally redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You **do not need `awk`**.Using AWS CLI, you are extracting 8 values first and then using `awk` to extract 2 values from that 8 values. Why? Just extract the 2 values from AWS CLI without using `awk`.

```
--query 'Reservations[*].[Instances[*].[InstanceId, [Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value][0][0]]]'
```

will return only the values you are interested in. Then use `xargs` to pass the arguments to your next command.

```
xargs -n2 command --arg1 $1 --arg2 $2
```

Your entire command becomes:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --profile proj --query 'Reservations[*].[Instances[*].[InstanceId, [Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value][0][0]]]'  --filter --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped | xargs -n2 aws ec2 create-image --profile proj --instance-id $1 --name $2 --no-reboot
```